# Dart - Define a list of Futures without calling them

Tags: dart

I have the following variable I want to populate with Future to pass to `Future.wait`

```
final List<Future<JSONData>> futures = [];
```

I need to dinamically define the content of the list above, I'm currently doing like it like this:

```
idsAndUrls.forEach((id, url) {
  futures.add(_downloadImage(id, url));
});
```

This runs `_downloadImage()` every time, which is kinda expected. Therefore, calling `Future.wait` on `futures` is useless.

How should I add to `futures` only the reference to the `_downloadImage` function without calling it, and call it later in Future.wait instead?

Comment: Calling `Future.wait` on the futures isn't necessarily useless.  While it's true that it synchronously calls `_downloadImage` for each element, those calls won't *complete* until `Future.wait` completes.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for the explanation, since I'm downloading quite a few images, I wanted to have them run in parallel in Future.wait, that's not what I'm doing here, am I?

Comment: Assuming that `_downloadImage` makes asynchronous HTTP requests, you'll be immediately *initiating* multiple downloads, and then `Future.wait` will wait for all of the downloads to complete.  The downloads themselves should occur in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prepare the image for loading, but not load it yet, you should store a function, not a future, in the list.

```dart
final List<Future<JSONData> Function()> loaders = [
  for (var e in idsAndUrls.entries) () => _downloadImage(e.key, e.value)
];
```

This stores one function for each ID/URL pair, you can then later go over the list and call the functions at once:

```
await Future.wait(loaders.map((f) => f());
```